# Convert Iterator to a for loop with index in order to skip objects

Tags: java, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I am using [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/index.html) to parse some malformed html. In particular I am trying to get all text nodes, process the text and then replace it.

I want to skip specific elements from processing. For example I want to skip all  elements, and any element that has attribute class="noProcess". So, if a div has class="noProcess" then I want to skip this div and all children from processing. However, I do want these skipped elements to return back to the output after processing.

Jericho provides an Iterator for all nodes but I am not sure how to skip complete elements from the Iterator. Here is my code:

```
private String doProcessHtml(String html) {
        Source source = new Source(html);
        OutputDocument outputDocument = new OutputDocument(source);

        for (Segment segment : source) {
            if (segment instanceof Tag) {
                Tag tag = (Tag) segment;
                System.out.println("FOUND TAG: " + tag.getName());

                // DO SOMETHING HERE TO SKIP ENTIRE ELEMENT IF IS <A> OR CLASS="noProcess"

            } else if (segment instanceof CharacterReference) {
                CharacterReference characterReference = (CharacterReference) segment;
                System.out.println("FOUND CHARACTERREFERENCE: " + characterReference.getCharacterReferenceString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("FOUND PLAIN TEXT: " + segment.toString());
                outputDocument.replace(segment, doProcessText(segment.toString()));
            }
        }

       return outputDocument.toString();
    }
```

It doesn't look like using the ignoreWhenParsing() method works for me as the parser just treats the "ignored" element as text.

I was thinking that if I could convert the Iterator loop to a for (int i = 0;...) loop I could probably be able to skip the element and all its children by modifying i to point to the EndTag and then continue the loop.... but not sure.

Comment: what about using `continue` keyword?

Comment: I could use continue but the next Segment will be the next child of the element I want to skip. The way it is working is that the Iterator returns all Segments. I need something that says: The EndTag of the element you want to skip is at position X. So skip to position X and continue

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
String skipTag = null;
for (Segment segment : source) {
    if (skipTag != null) { // is skipping ON?
        if (segment instanceof EndTag && // if EndTag found for the
            skipTag.equals(((EndTag) segment).getName())) { // tag we're skipping
            skipTag = null; // set skipping OFF
        }
        continue; // continue skipping (or skip the EndTag)
    } else if (segment instanceof Tag) { // is tag?
        Tag tag = (Tag) segment;
        System.out.println("FOUND TAG: " + tag.getName());
        if (HTMLElementName.A.equals(tag.getName()) { // if <a> ?
            skipTag = tag.getName(); // set
            continue; // skipping ON
        } else if (tag instanceof StartTag) {
            if ("noProcess".equals( // if <tag class="noProcess" ..> ?
                    ((StartTag) tag).getAttributeValue("class"))) {
                skipTag = tag.getName(); // set
                continue; // skipping ON
            }
        }
    } // ...
}
```

Comment: continue will not do it. It doesn't skip the entire element. It just skips the specific Tag object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consider a redesign of the way your segments are built. Is there a way to parse the html in such a way that each segment is a parent element that contains a nested list of child elements? That way you could do something like:

```
for (Segment segment : source) {
        if (segment instanceof Tag) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) segment;
            System.out.println("FOUND TAG: " + tag.getName());

            // DO SOMETHING HERE TO SKIP ENTIRE ELEMENT IF IS <A> OR CLASS="noProcess"
            continue;

        } else if (segment instanceof CharacterReference) {
            CharacterReference characterReference = (CharacterReference) segment;
            System.out.println("FOUND CHARACTERREFERENCE: " + characterReference.getCharacterReferenceString());
            for(Segment child : segment.childNodes()) {
                //Use recursion to process child elements
                //You will want to put your for loop in a separate method so it can be called recursively.
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("FOUND PLAIN TEXT: " + segment.toString());
            outputDocument.replace(segment, doProcessText(segment.toString()));
        }
    }
```

Without more code to inspect its hard to determine if restructuring the segment element is even possible or worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to have a working solution by using the getEnd() method of the Element object of the Tag. The idea is to skip elements if their end position is less than a position you set. So you find the end position of the element you want to exclude and you do not process anything else before that position:

```
final ArrayList<String> excludeTags = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"head", "script", "a"}));
final ArrayList<String> excludeClasses = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"noProcess"}));

Source.LegacyIteratorCompatabilityMode = true;
Source source = new Source(htmlToProcess);
OutputDocument outputDocument = new OutputDocument(source);

int skipToPos = 0;
for (Segment segment : source) {
    if (segment.getBegin() >= skipToPos) {
        if (segment instanceof Tag) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) segment;
            Element element = tag.getElement();

            // check excludeTags
            if (excludeTags.contains(tag.getName().toLowerCase())) {
                skipToPos = element.getEnd();
            }

            // check excludeClasses
            String classes = element.getAttributeValue("class");
            if (classes != null) {
                for (String theClass : classes.split(" ")) {
                    if (excludeClasses.contains(theClass.toLowerCase())) {
                        skipToPos = element.getEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        } else if (segment instanceof CharacterReference) { // for future use. Source.LegacyIteratorCompatabilityMode = true;
            CharacterReference characterReference = (CharacterReference) segment;
        } else {
            outputDocument.replace(segment, doProcessText(segment.toString()));
        }
    }
}

return outputDocument.toString();
```